# How do I play a video using pygame?

Tags: python, video, pygame

I want to play a video as a background in a pygame window, and draw some images on it, like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQfC0.jpg

However, since pygame no longer has `pygame.movie` module I'm wondering what could be the alternative way of playing video in pygame window.

Answer (score 3):

You can use moviepy module to display videos now since pygame.movie is removed. MoviePy will display the video with pygame. Here's an example:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
import pygame

pygame.display.set_caption('My video!')

clip = VideoFileClip('myvideo.mp4')
clip.preview()
pygame.quit()
```

You can also visit their [docs](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html) for mor explanation

Comment: this works wonderful. But I notice once clip.preview() execute, code stay there until the end of the movie(in this case, video). If I were to draw some images on it  [link](http://imgur.com/a/qRiEe) like this, which feature of moviepy should I look for ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert on moviepy only used it a few times and have never edited it myself. Perhaps check though the editor, there's many useful features.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cv2` module *([OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/))* that can be installed with the command prompt command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Then, you can run the code:

```
import cv2
import pygame

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
success, img = cap.read()
shape = img.shape[1::-1]
wn = pygame.display.set_mode(shape)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while success:
    clock.tick(60)
    success, img = cap.read()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            success = False
    wn.blit(pygame.image.frombuffer(img.tobytes(), shape, "BGR"), (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```